# Using RKMappingResult to fetch core data through a To Many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have an iOS app using restKit to pull data from a server and persisting it into core data.

***BACKGROUND INFORMATION***

The response from the server has nested objects.  See below.

```
<node>
    <entryDate>2013-08-31T20:08:53-06:00</entryDate>
    <followId>0</followId>
    <ipAddress>255.255.255.0</ipAddress>
    <likeStatus>-3</likeStatus>
    <nodeId>20</nodeId>
    <personId>2</personId>

    <point>
        <city>Bluffdale</city>
        <copy>An amazing discovery was unearthed as a local farmer was plowing his field</copy>
        <entryDate>2013-08-31T20:08:53-06:00</entryDate>
        <ipAddress>255.255.255.0</ipAddress>            
        //..... removed some to be concise
        <trend>0.0</trend>
    </point>

    <point>
       //there are many points per node all which contain fields like above
    </point>

</node>
```

I have created two entities.  One for the Node level data and one for the Point level data.  I have a one to many relationship between the two and I am mapping the results like so.

```
RKEntityMapping *nodeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"NodeLevel" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [nodeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"followId.text":             @"followId",
     @"likeStatus.text":           @"likeStatus",
     @"nodeId.text":               @"nodeId",
     @"personId.text":             @"personId",
     @"entryDate.text":            @"entryDate"}];

nodeMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"nodeId" ];

RKEntityMapping *pointMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"PointLevel" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [pointMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"nodeId.text":               @"nodeId",
     @"copy.text":                 @"paragraph",
     //....removed some to be concise    
     @"trend.text":                @"trend"}];

    pointMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"pointId" ];

    [nodeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"point" toKeyPath:@"node" withMapping:pointMapping]];
```

Currently the node level data is mapped to the node entity and the point level data is mapped to the point entity.  Here is where I run into trouble.

***PROBLEM***

There are many points in any given node.  Each of them has a `<copy>` field that I need to use to populate a UITextView.  This is the code I have been using with non-nested responses and it works perfectly.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:getArticle parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    self.htmlString = [[mappingResult.firstObject valueForKey:@"paragraph"]description];

        if (self.htmlString != nil) {

            NSDictionary *options = @{DTUseiOS6Attributes: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]};
            NSData *htmlData = [self.htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSAttributedString *stringArticle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData options:options documentAttributes:NULL];
            self.newsDetailText.attributedText = stringArticle;
        }

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

But now that I am mapping a nested response an exception is thrown because `the entity NodeLevel is not key value coding-compliant for the key "paragraph"`

Utilizing the RKMappingResult is super handy but I'm not sure how to designate what entity to pull from.

Could someone spell this out for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RKMappingResult` can give you an array of all of the objects that have been processed. The first object in that array should be the outer object. You may find it better to log the array and the dictionary provided by the mapping result to check exactly what you get out.

Anyway, the first object in the array should be the instance of `NodeLevel` which itself doesn't have a `paragraph` property. Each of the associated `PointLevel` instances have that property.

You may have direct access to the points from the mapping result, but you certainly have access to them via the relationship (which seems to be named `node`?). The question then is how you decide which one of the points you want to get the `paragraph` from.

Comment: Wain, you bring up a good point in your last paragraph.  I need to display the `paragraph` instance from every point.  I spent a good deal of time last night just trying to decide where to start with the issue I am facing.  I would like to pick your brain for the best way to handle the situation but I will stick to the topic of the question.  Do you know if it is possible to access the `PointLevel` via the mapping result or do I need to perform a fetch request for the data?

Comment: It is available in the mapping result - but that doesn't mean it's correct to use it from there. I guess you're using a table view? Why not use an FRC as the source of data and use the objects it provides you with to get the paragraphs?

Comment: To clarify the content of the each paragraph instance needs to go into a common UITextView. When the project started there was no PointLevel data. So there was only one `paragraph` instance. It may be necassary to move to a table view in the future but for now I am experimenting in getting a UITextView to work. With that knowledge how do I proceed. Using a fetch request to compile all the PointLevel paragraph instances or using the mapping result. If mapping result is the answer HOW... I can't seem to find any way to designate the entity or relationship

Comment: Ok, work with the mapping result for now then. Iterate over the points (`for (NSString *paragraph in [[mappingResult.firstObject valueForKey:@"node"] valueForKey:@"paragraph"]) { ...`). Check the names of the keys (and break the line down into parts to get the array of points and then the array of paragraphs. Then inside the loop you can append them all together (use `NSMutableString`).

Comment: Thanks Wain, `[[mappingResult.firstObject valueForKey:@"node"] valueForKey:@"paragraph"]` was just what I needed to access content of the pointLevel entity!  Unfortunately I don't believe using the mappingResult will work after all.  The items come in out of order.  According to the RKMappingResult documentation "`No guarantee is made as to the ordering of objects within the returned collection when more than one key path was mapped, as `NSDictionary` objects are unordered."`  Unless you have another trick up your sleeve I will hang up the attempt to use the mappingResult.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I'll throw this out as well.  There is a sequence attribute sent in the pointLevel instances.  The sequence identifies what order the points go in.  The database manager threw it in so we could know we are ordering the point data properly.  I could potentially use that to reorder the points after retrieving them from the mappingResult.  Worth the effort or is there a better/more appropriate way.

Comment: If you are supplied with an ordering then mapping and using it is the best idea.